# SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED installing Python package on Windows 10

Tags: python, ssl, installation

I am unable to install any packages using pip install in Windows 10. Here is the sample.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Pro tip: don't paste screenshots. Not everyone can see them and it is hard to cut & paste when testing or replying.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Windows 10, was running:

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org python-certifi-win32`

Most solutions just name `<package_name>` instead of specifying `python-certifi-win32`.